# Equivalence of DB2_GENERATED_DOCID_FOR_XML in db2luw

Tags: xml, db2, db2-luw

In DB2, A table with an XML column has a DocID column, used to link from the base table to the XML table. 
A DocID index is used for getting to base table rows from XML indexes.And it has the following syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name
  (DB2_GENERATED_DOCID_FOR_XML ASC
  );
```

Is there an equivalent index for db2luw ?

Answer (score 1):

DB2 LUW has a similar index, the XML Region Index. It is a system index that is automatically generated when the first XML column is added to a table. You can find some information in the [docs about the XML path index and XML regions index](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0024071.html).

Also take a look at [SYSCAT.INDEXES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001047.html) and the INDEXTYPE column.